# Linq Method for Intersecting with a Condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following POCO:

```
public class User {
    public ICollection<DepartmentPosition> DepartmentPositions { get; set; }
    public PerformanceRecord PerformanceRecord { get; set; }
}
```

where `DepartmentPosition` is defined as:

```
public class DepartmentPosition {
   public Department Department { get; set; }
   public PositionType PositionType { get; set; }
}
```

and `PositionType` is a enum defined as:

```
 public enum PositionType : byte {
     Employee = 0,
     Manager = 1
 }
```

I want to be able to query whether a `Manager` is able to see an `Employee` `PeformanceRecord`.

The criteria for this is:

If a Manager has a `DepartmentPosition` with a `PositionType` of `Manager`, and that particular `DepartmentPosition` also has a `Department` equal to the `Department` of any of the Employee's `DepartmentPositions`, then the Manager will be able to see the Performance Record for the Employee.

There is a specification class being used for this:

```
public CanUserSeePerformanceRecord() {
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(User fooUser, User barUser) {
         // PSUEDO CODE

         // Returns true if:

         // fooUser and barUser both have a DepartmentPosition with the same Department AND for barUser, the PositionType of the DepartmentPosition is Manager
    }
}
```

I think you could do it using a Linq Intersect or similar, but not sure how to include the condition that the `barUser` has to hold a `DepartmentPosition` that is marked as `Manager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Department has an ID field to uniquely identify it. You should be able to do this:

```
return barUser.DepartmentPositions
         .Where(x => x.PositionType == PositionType.Manager)
         .Select(x => x.Department.Id)
         .Intersect(fooUser.DepartmentPositions.Select(x => X.Department.Id))
         .Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show another way, you may also use a join

```
return (
        from dBar in barUser.DepartmentPositions
                            .Where(m => m.PositionType == PositionType.Manager)
        join dFoo in fooUser.DepartmentPositions 
                 on dBar.Department.Id equals dFoo.Department.Id
        select 1)
      .Any()
```

or

```
(
 from dBar in barUser.DepartmentPositions                              
 join dFoo in fooUser.DepartmentPositions 
                     on dBar.Department.Id equals dFoo.Department.Id
 where dBar.PositionType == PositionType.Manager
 select 1)
 .Any()
```